# Cordova: FileWriter.writeAsDataURL?

Tags: cordova, file-io

I want to be able to write arbitrary gobbledygook to disk using Cordova (specifically, audio files), I can see there's a `FileReader.readAsDataURL`, but no corresponding `FileWriter.writeAsDataURL`.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to write via **Cordova [File](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md) plugin**.

It allows read/write access to files residing on the device. It also implements the **FileWriter** spec : http://dev.w3.org/2009/dap/file-system/file-writer.html

A good article on **File System API**: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/